# read/write from a .txt file iOS 7 objc

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code:

```
  NSString *studentList = _textIn.text;
NSString *path = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory].path
                  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ClassOne.txt"];
[studentList writeToFile:path atomically:YES
               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", studentList);
NSLog(@"students 1 saved");
```

I try to write to a text file on the phone system. When I try to read from that file with:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *strFileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                               pathForResource: @"classOne" ofType: @"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
_textIn.text = strFileContent;
```

The textfield comes up blank. The NSLog prints what was in the text field but when I try to load it up later the textfield is empty. how do I get the textfield to display what is in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The writing part is alright. You are trying to read the file from your application main bundle instead of your original file path.

Comment: Also: log the error returned from stringWithContentsOfFile:.  It'd probably tell you that the file isn't found--which would clue you into the fact that you're reading from the wrong path.